# Excluding "seen" database rows for many users

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

In the iPhone app "Houzz", you can flick through millions of photos of home interior, one by one.

I assume they are storing which photos you have seen in a database, then doing something like the query below, and querying again when the user has seen the first 100 photos.

```
select photos.id from photos left join seen ... 
where seen.id is null and user.id = $USERID order by photos.created desc 
limit 100
```

This works well with a few thousand users and a few thousand photos, but with millions of photos, and a growing number of users looking at them, this grows exponentially and will break down.

How do you solve a problem like this with a single, preferably relational, database server?

Or is it simply one of those things that aren't doable without resorting to huge clusters of database servers and all the complexity and headache that comes with it?

Note! It is a prerequisite that the query needs to be ordered to include newly arrived photos relatively often (if not immediately).

Comment: Can we see an EXPLAIN and proper DDLs for each table in the query.

Comment: Also, do not use SELECT *. Instead name all and only the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: Well, the question is very general, so the answer could also be only very general: `please read this chapter devoted to optimizing queries:` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization.html The query provided in the question is only a pseudocode, it's hard to guess how join condition look like, how many tables are joined, are there any indexes created, what is a type of `created` column etc. If you want to optimize the query, please provide more detalis, at least the the entire query. For now I vote to close the question as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly prefer "not exists" over the left join-- it should be faster.

```
select photos.id from photos
where not exists
(select 1 from seen where user.id=$USERID and seen.photoId=photos.id)
order by photos.created desc 
limit 100
```

You also may update by "last upload date" or something to further limit the pictures from that scope.. perhaps only showing pics that are x number of months old.. which should usually cover your 100 pic limit or something like that.